# Where online can I find arguments for preference utilitarianism?

Tags: ethics, utilitarianism

I'm looking for (emphasis on) open access arguments for preference utilitarianism over hedonistic (or other alternative forms) of utilitarianism. Here's the current list (I don't have enough rep to post them as full URLs, but hopefully if you know them, you'll recognise them):

[Harsanyi's Utilitarian Theorem](http://www.hks.harvard.edu/fs/mrisse/Papers/Papers%20-%20Philosophy/HarsanyisUtilitarianTheorem.pdf) ; [Not for the Sake of Pleasure Alone](http://lesswrong.com/lw/65w/not_for_the_sake_of_pleasure_alone/) ;
[Not for the sake of Happiness Alone](http://lesswrong.com/lw/lb/not_for_the_sake_of_happiness_alone/) ;
Nozick machine section of Internet Encyclopedia of Philosophy ;
[Choose Pain-Free Utilitarianism](http://meteuphoric.wordpress.com/2009/10/30/choose-pain-free-utilitarianism/) ;
hedonistic-vs-preference.html ;
hedonic_vs_preference_utilitarianism_in_the context of wireheading ;
multiversewide_preference_utilitarianism ;
http://felicifia.org/old/www.felicifia.com/showDiary.do_diaryId=97
And possibly something by Alonzo Fyfe, though I'm not sure what yet.

Comment: This seems to be a poorly constructed question insofar as it's asking for lists. Maybe there could be a place on meta for lists (they do that for learning resources at Japanese.SE)?

Answer (score 3):

- [Hedonistic vs. Preference Utilitarianism](http://www.utilitarian-essays.com/hedonistic-vs-preference.html) by Brian Tomasik is an excellent and thorough essay detailing arguments both for and against preference utilitarianism.
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SR-tzgU07XY is a piece of philosophical history: Professor Peter Singer, one of the major proponents of preference utilitarianism  explains the idea of the experience machine and other things which originally convinced him of preference utilitarianism, and then goes on to describe why he changed his mind back to a hedonistic approach.
- For a wider overview of the topic see the Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy entry on  consequentialism: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the National Debate Coaches' Association's [Open Evidence Project](http://www.debatecoaches.org/resources/open-evidence-project/open-evidence-2012-2013/). There are plenty of cards there that you can find promoting utilitarianism over deontology, ontology, or other competing ethical standards. On the linked page, click on "Impact Files" and look for anything along the lines of "Util Good".